# Submit button is not working in html using django

Tags: python, html, django, backend, web-development-server

[HTML FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nC2M8.png)

in html page action is not added i wanted to know how i can submit the form without adding action attribute??

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, add it as formatted text to your question. Your submit input should be inside the form tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add your *submit* in the *form* tag:

```
<form method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
   <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

and if you don't want that, so use *form=* in submit:

```
<form method="post" id="this_form">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{form.as_p}}
 </form>
<input type="submit" form="this_form" value="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```